# TimeZone issue with ibatis ORM and postgres

Tags: java, jdbc, orm, ibatis, timestamp-with-timezone

Please suggest, I am retrieving data using ibatis ORM from postgres database.

When I fire the below query using ibatis the timestamp "PVS.SCHED_DTE" get reduced to "2013-06-07 23:30:00.0" where as in db timestamp is "2013-06-08 05:00:00.0".

Though when the same query is executed using `postgresAdminII`, its gives proper PVS.SCHED_DTE.

```
SELECT PVS.PTNT_VISIT_SCHED_NUM,   PVS.PTNT_ID,P.FIRST_NAM AS   PTNT_FIRST_NAM,P.PRIM_EMAIL_TXT,P.SCNDRY_EMAIL_TXT,   PVS.PTNT_NOTIFIED_FLG,PVS.SCHED_DTE,PVS.VISIT_TYPE_NUM,PVS.DURTN_TYPE_NUM,PVS.ROUTE_TYPE_NUM,   C.FIRST_NAM AS CARE_FIRST_NAM,C.MIDDLE_INIT_NAM AS   CARE_MIDDLE_NAM,C.LAST_NAM AS CARE_LAST_NAM,   C.PHONE_NUM_1,ORGNIZATN.EMAIL_HOST_SERVER_TXT,ORGNIZATN.PORT_NUM,   ORGNIZATN.MAIL_SENDER_USER_ID,ORGNIZATN.MAIL_SENDER_PSWD_DESC,ORGNIZATN.SOCKET_FCTRY_PORT_DESC,   ORGNIZATN.TIMEZONE_ID   FROM IHCAS.PTNT_VISIT_SCHED PVS ,   IHCAS.PTNT P,   IHCAS.ROUTE_LEG RL,   IHCAS.ROUTE R, IHCAS.CAREGIVER C,IHCAS.ORG   ORGNIZATN WHERE   ORGNIZATN.ORG_NUM = ? AND   PVS.SCHED_STAT_CDE = '2002' AND   PVS.PTNT_NOTIFIED_FLG =   FALSE      AND **PVS.SCHED_DTE >= (CURRENT_DATE + interval '1 day') AT TIME ZONE ? at TIME ZONE 'UTC'**   AND **PVS.SCHED_DTE < (CURRENT_DATE + interval '2 day' - interval '1 sec') AT TIME ZONE  ? at TIME ZONE 'UTC'**   AND PVS.PTNT_ID = P.PTNT_ID AND PVS.PTNT_VISIT_SCHED_NUM =   RL.PTNT_VISIT_SCHED_NUM   AND   RL.ROUTE_NUM = R.ROUTE_NUM AND   C.CAREGIVER_NUM=R.ASGN_TO_CAREGIVER_NUM   AND PVS.ORG_NUM=   ORGNIZATN.ORG_NUM   ORDER BY PVS.SCHED_DTE   ASC,PVS.ROUTE_TYPE_NUM   ASC,PVS.ORG_NUM ASC   
Parameters: **[1, EST, EST]**

Header: [PTNT_VISIT_SCHED_NUM, PTNT_NOTIFIED_FLG, **SCHED_DTE**, VISIT_TYPE_NUM, DURTN_TYPE_NUM, ROUTE_TYPE_NUM, PTNT_ID, PTNT_FIRST_NAM, PRIM_EMAIL_TXT, SCNDRY_EMAIL_TXT, CARE_FIRST_NAM, CARE_MIDDLE_NAM, CARE_LAST_NAM, PHONE_NUM_1, EMAIL_HOST_SERVER_TXT, PORT_NUM, MAIL_SENDER_USER_ID, MAIL_SENDER_PSWD_DESC, SOCKET_FCTRY_PORT_DESC, TIMEZONE_ID]
Result: [1129, false, **2013-06-07 23:30:00.0**, 1002, 1551, 1702, PID146, Ricky, Receiver.test@******.com, , Vikas, S, Jain, 956-**-5**8, 172.17.*.***, 25, Sender.test@******.com, ********123, 465, EST]
```

For me.. it seems to be some timezone issue but what and how to resolve.
N.B : Local Time zone : IST
Application Time zone : EST
In database, datatype of column is timestamp without timezone.

Any suggestion.. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be best to set the database timezone to UTC and implement an UTC-preserving MyBatis type handler as shown in the accepted answer to this:
[What's the right way to handle UTC date-times using Java, iBatis, and Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653402/whats-the-right-way-to-handle-utc-date-times-using-java-ibatis-and-oracle).